# Can't edit main.js for Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, osx-mavericks, parse-cloud-code

I have is installed Parse Cloud Code on my Mac but I can't edit the main.js to edit my cloud code. What am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that you missed a critical step.

Answer (score 0):

To Edit Cloud Code we have to first Traverse To the **Cloud Code Folder**
which in clude 3 Folders namely cloud,config,node_modules.

Your main.js will be in **cloud** folder.

open that and edit the main.js page
then save it.

After saving,
the main step is pushing the code to parse.com.

in parse console type command **parse deploy**

after successfull deploy your code will be on parse.com.

Comment: is main.js page supposed to open in safari? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can open the file ,but there will be  nothing to view since is a JavaScript File we can see the main.js into the parse login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **parse.com** command line tool: you edit locally in your machine, and then deploy your code.
More info, in parse.com documentacion: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code